# Convert a BiFunction into a Function in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Let's say I have the following enum :

```java
public enum Foo {

  AAA(new A()::doA),
  BBB(new B()::doB),
  CCC(new C()::doC),
  DDD(new D()::doD);

  private Function<String, Number> do;

  Foo(Function<String, Number> do) {
    this.do = do;
  }

  public Function<String, Number> getDo() {
    return do;
  }  
}
```

*Knowing that I **must** keep the `getDo` method with the exact same signature.*

This works fine, if I do `AAA.getDo().apply("two")`, I will get `2` as a result.
But the problem is that each call to the `do` method will always be done on the same instances of A, B, C and D. However, **I need A, B, C or D to be a different instance at each call** (Because these classes have fields, and I do not want these fields to keep their values throughout every call of the `do` method).

I thought about something like this :

```java
AAA(
  A.class,
  A::doA);
```

However in this case `A::doA` is not a Function on an instance of A anymore, but a BiFunction to which I need to pass an instance of A as first parameter.
But my `getDo` method still have to return a Function, and I do not see any way to turn my BiFunction and my A class, to a Function on A instance (we could imagine something like : `(A::DoA).toFunction(A.class)`).

Comment: You say you want to be able to invoke the `Function` on different instances. But a `Function` isn't invoked on an instance - please show us how you intend to do that. If you want to be able to change the instance on which you invoke, you need your `getDo()` method to return a `BiFunction` (note though - you can't use `do` as a variable name in Java since it's a keyword - much better to test your code before posting)

Comment: Can you explain to me how it makes a difference whether the same instance is used to call a method or whether a different instance is used each time.  In either case method does not change and the other fields are not accessible.

Comment: @WJS I think this has to do with the characteristics of these classes. It's likely that `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are not thread-safe and the OP needs to be working with a new instance of , e.g., `A` each time `Foo.AAA.getDo().apply(...)` is invoked.

Comment: @ernest_k I had not considered multiple threads accessing the `enum`.  Makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @WJS Even without Threads, imagine my A class have a variable `int i = 0` and that in the `doA` method I have `i++` at some point. Since the instance of `A` is always the same at each call of `doA`, my variable will never be reset, so at the third call of `doA`, I will start with `i = 2` instead of `i = 0`.

Comment: @JordanRepovy I agree that would be the situation. But since you want new instances each time, that means you want the variable to be reset each time. Which seems to me that you could just use local variables in the method and not even worry about instance fields since it's a `throw away instance`.  On the other hand, I can see how if you were `forced` to use new instances, you might want a `singleton` so you can `increment a counter` if you choose.  Perhaps a more complicated example is needed for me to understand.   Fortunately, you can do it either way.

Comment: Note that the reason why the variable name `do` is shown with a blue text color in the code example, is, that `do` is a keyword and not a legal variable name.

Comment: @Holger Yes I did not think of that when writing the question :)

Comment: @WJS I do not have the hand on every class that will be in that enum. In fact, the example I showed in my question worked fine for months because most people didn't use fields in their process class. But one day it happend, and it didn't work as expected... This enum **must** work in every scenario, thread, fields, singleton...etc. I just wrote the architecture but I am not the only one adding data in this enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method reference `new A()::doA` is bound to the one `A` object created when `new A()::doA` is evaluated to create the `Function` instance, i.e., when the enum value `AAA` is being created. `new A()` is executed immediately and a reference to its `doA()` method returned, just as though you had used `someInstanceOfA::doA`.

The way to fix it is to make the function itself call the constructor in the logic that's not run immediately:

```
AAA(s -> new A().doA(s)), 
BBB(s -> new B().doB(s)), 
CCC(s -> new C().doC(s)), 
DDD(s -> new D().doD(s));
```

Comment: Based on your proposition, I did it like this : `AAA(() -> new A()::doA)`

Comment: @JordanRepovy this doesn’t make sense, `() -> new A()::doA` is not the same as `s -> new A().doA(s)` and there is no reason to try to bring in a method reference at all costs.

Comment: I know it does not the same, but this is just an example. In our project we do not manipulate only function, we created functional interfaces for Function and Consumer up to 6 parameters, and this enum can handle all of them. This enum is crazy generic and has to work with every class and method that people might create. Here you only have a tiny bit a the architecture so I understand why it seems pointless, but it isn't.